# DataTable row filling in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow, arrays

I am trying to add row in DataTable CartDT using row[], which is a string array.

```
DataTable CartDT = new DataTable();
    public void DataTableColumn()
    {
        CartDT.Columns.Add("Product_Name", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("Product_ID", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("ItemQTY", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", typeof(string));

    }
    protected void AddToCart(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(arg[3]);
        TextBox itemQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].FindControl("txtQty");
        string[] row = new string[5];
        row[0] = arg[0];  //Product_Name
        row[1] = arg[1]; //Product_ID
        row[2] = itemQuantity.Text; //OrderQTY
        row[3] = arg[2]; //Price
 row[4]=(Double.Parse(arg[2]) * Convert.ToInt32(itemQuantity.Text)).ToString();// calculate total price 
        CartDT.Rows.Add(row);//Creating row in Datatable using row[] string array


        GridView2.DataSource = CartDT;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Now when I execute it, it gives the error that "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table" 
The array row[] has exactly 5 elements in it & also DataTable CartDT has also 5 columns.
Now i am not able to find exactly where i am wrong.
Please help me to find the bug.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what line throws an error, chances are it's referencing some other array

Comment: just ran the portion of your code that does the row insert, worked just fine. I obviously had to hard-code all the Product values.

Comment: Just curious but did you even bother googling "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table" and working it out by yourself? Please read the [FAQ]'s and do research before you ask simple questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead do this

```
DataRow dr = CartDT.NewRow();
```

Then

```
dr[0] = arg[0];
```

and so on. In the end

```
 CartDT.Rows.Add(dr);
 CartDT.AcceptChanges();
```

This way the instance of Row will have CartDT schema.

```
DataTable CartDT = new DataTable();

public void CreateDataTableColumns()
{
    CartDT.Columns.Add("Product_Name", typeof(string));
    CartDT.Columns.Add("Product_ID", typeof(string));
    CartDT.Columns.Add("ItemQTY", typeof(string));
    CartDT.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
    CartDT.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", typeof(string));
}

protected void AddToCart(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (CartDT.Columns.Count = 0)
    {
        CreateDataTableColumns();
    }

    string[] arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');

    int index = Convert.ToInt32(arg[3]);            
    TextBox itemQuantity = 
           (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].FindControl("txtQty");

    DataRow dr = CartDT.NewRow();
    dr[0] = arg[0];  //Product_Name
    dr[1] = arg[1]; //Product_ID
    dr[2] = itemQuantity.Text; //OrderQTY
    dr[3] = arg[2]; //Price
    dr[4] = (Double.Parse(arg[2]) * Convert.ToInt32(itemQuantity.Text)).ToString(); // calculate total price

    CartDT.Rows.Add(dr);
    CartDT.AcceptChanges();

    GridView2.DataSource = CartDT;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug, and break on

```
CartDT.Rows.Add(row);
```

and see how many columns are in CartDT; I think you don't call `DataTableColumn()` at the right time.

Your code having to do with row insertion works just fine

```
        DataTable CartDT = new DataTable();

        CartDT.Columns.Add("Product_Name", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("Product_ID", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("ItemQTY", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
        CartDT.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", typeof(string));



        string[] row = new string[5];

        row[0] = "1";  //Product_Name
        row[1] = "2"; //Product_ID
        row[2] = "3"; //OrderQTY
        row[3] = "4"; //Price
        row[4] = "5";// calculate total price 
        CartDT.Rows.Add(row);//Creating row in Datatable using row[] string array

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CartDT.Rows[0][i]);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
  protected void AddToCart(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(arg[3]);
        TextBox itemQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[6].FindControl("txtQty");
        DataRow row = CartDT.NewRow();
        row["Product_Name"] = arg[0];  //Product_Name
        row["Product_ID"] = arg[1]; //Product_ID
        row["OrderQTY"] = itemQuantity.Text; //OrderQTY
        row["Price"] = arg[2]; //Price
        row["TotalPrice"]=(Double.Parse(arg[2]) * Convert.ToInt32(itemQuantity.Text)).ToString();
        CartDt.Rows.Add(row);
        CartDT.AcceptChanges();    
        GridView2.DataSource = CartDT;
        GridView2.DataBind();
     }
```

Comment: You only need the `DataBind()` for ASP.Net